# Alternative for `express-http-context` in Nextjs?

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, middleware

With Express.js, I can store and load the context by using the `express-http-context` middleware.

Something like this

```
const httpContext = require("express-http-context");

app.use(httpContext.middleware);
httpContext.set("CO_APP_ID", parseCookies(req).co_app_id);
```

If then, I was able to get `CO_APP_ID` everywhere in the code during the request is proceeding without passing the request data or response data.

For example, at `utils.js`, I can use like this.

```
import httpContext from 'express-http-context';
function addCoAppId = (obj) => {
    const coAppId = httpContext.get('CO_APP_ID);
    return {...obj, coAppId}
}
```

I believe there will be a similar solution on Next.js.

If anyone have any idea for it can you please give me some tips?